# vuex state Not reset after changing routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm using Nuxt js and I have a multi-step form that can be used by the user to apply for jobs.

when the page opens I'm fetching the company's data using async and putting it in the vuex state.

I also use `activeStep` in vuex to determine the current step .

```
export const state = () => ({
  companyProfile: "",
  fullname: "",
  Myapplications: "",
  activeStep: 1,
});
```

going to the next step `action` :

```
 goToNextStep({ commit, state }, step) {
    commit("setStep", step);
  },
/// Mutation
 setStep(state, step) {
    state.activeStep = step;
  },
```

this is working fine when the user uses the form the step works perfectly.

The issue is when the user goes to another page and opens a company apply form, the active step is still the last one from the previous submission

This is how I'm handling the steps on my page :

```
//activeStep is a computed property 

   <Step1 v-if="activeStep === 1" />
        <transition
          name="slide-fade"
          v-if="activeStep=== 2"
          mode="in-out"
        >
          <Step2 />
        </transition>
        <transition
          name="slide-fade"
          mode="out-in"
          v-if="activeStep === 3"
        >
          <Step3 />
        </transition>
```

I tried resetting the state in vuex `beforeMount` the components but I'm getting a weird behavior where the `transition` of the steps isn't working. I have to refresh the entire page to get the correct behavior.

am I missing something here related to vue? or should it be done without vuex ?

Comment: See how you've got ```v-if``` on your ```<Step1/>``` component, but you've placed ```v-if``` on the ```<transition>``` component for the others? Move ```v-if``` to ```<Step2/>``` and ```<Step3/>```. You haven't really explained the "weird behaviour", but I suspect that is playing a part... let us know how that goes, and we can help further.

Comment: @NickDawes ‍♂️ sigh .. that solved it . I moved both step2 & step3 to transition and used mode out in and v-else-if on step3 .. thank you